# Problem sending utf-8 display name in Gmail API

Tags: python, gmail-api, email-headers

So I have a function which I use to send emails through Gmail API:

```
def send_email(payload, messagesubject, sendtoaddresses, key_file_path: str, subject: str):
    messagedraft = MIMEText(payload, "plain")
    mailservice = build_mail_service(key_file_path, subject)
    messagedraft["From"] = f"Display name <{subject}>"
    messagedraft["Subject"] = messagesubject
    for address in sendtoaddresses.split(","):
        if "To" in messagedraft:
            del messagedraft["To"]
        messagedraft["To"] = address
        message = {"raw": urlsafe_b64encode(messagedraft.as_bytes()).decode()}
        mailservice.users().messages().send(userId="me", body=message).execute()
```

And everything works well aside from the fact that if the "Display name" in the "From" field has a utf-8 character it gets omitted and only the email address shows up in the header.

I've tried various encoding settings found throughout the internet and stackoverflow but nothing has fixed it. The only thing that works is when I change the utf-8 character into ascii

I'm trying to understand why this problem shows up and how I can fix this behaviour.

Comment: You probably need to RFC2047-encode it. Python does this transparently if you use the `email` module but perhaps this is not implemented in the Gmail API. See the basic example in https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.header.html

Comment: I tried using the Header class in the form `messagedraft["From"] = Header(f"Display name <{subject}>", "utf-8")` this also didn't work

Comment: Try `Header(f"Display name <{address}>", "utf-8").encode()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While inspecting the documentation linked by tripleee [Problem sending utf-8 display name in Gmail API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77330887/problem-sending-utf-8-display-name-in-gmail-api#comment136329743_77330887) I was struck by a new idea and replaced `MIMEText` class with `EmailMessage` class.
Below is the solution that worked for me for future reference.

```
def send_email(payload, messagesubject, sendtoaddresses, key_file_path: str, subject: str):
    messagedraft = EmailMessage()
    messagedraft.set_payload(payload)
    mailservice = build_mail_service(key_file_path, subject)
    messagedraft.add_header("From", f"Display name <{subject}>")
    messagedraft.add_header("Subject", messagesubject)
    messagedraft.add_header("To", "")
    for address in sendtoaddresses.split(","):
        messagedraft.replace_header("To", address)
        message = {"raw": urlsafe_b64encode(messagedraft.as_bytes()).decode()}
        mailservice.users().messages().send(userId="me", body=message).execute()
```